# What is the mechanism behind rendering web pages locally?

Tags: windows, iis

When I visit a web site, my browser sends a request to a an HTTP server, such as Apache or IIS. The HTTP server then forwards the request to the appropriate web server, .NET, PHP, Ruby on Rails, etc. This then returns a response to my browser and the page is rendered.

How does this work on a local web page? Say I create a simply hello world in PHP (hello.php) on my windows desktop. I do not have IIS installed, so what is handling the "request"? That is, what is telling my request to be interpreted by php and how is this getting back to my browser? I have tried several google searches, but I suspect my search terms may be too vague.

Comment: Evidently, you're running _some_ sort of PHP server.

Comment: @MattBall So when I open my `hello.php` file in a browser, is my request going straight to a php server based on the extension, or is there some sort of intermediary that passes the request to the php server, similar to what Apache does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit ambiguous. A PHP file on a disk simply won't be rendered unless it is present within the Document Root configured for the web server.

For example if your file is present within C:\PHP_Scripts, then C:\PHP_Scripts **must** be configured as a document root for your web server.

For more information on how to setup document roots within Apache HTTP server refer to the below link :
[Apache Web server Document Root creation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#documentroot)

Having said this, in your case assuming the file (say test.php) is now present under C:\PHP_Scripts and this has been configured to be part of the Document Root of the web server; the following happens when you request `http://localhost/test.php`:

1. The web server refers to the document root and searches for the file named test.php.
2. Since this is a php file, the PHP interpretor kicks in and processes the script.
3. The results of the processing are rendered back to the user. In some cases, the processing may be a task like submitting the data to a backend and redirecting the user to another page.

Note that Apache HTTPD server must be configured to work with PHP for all the above to be true.

Comment: So it would be impossible for a php file to be rendered without an HTTP server? It does not matter whether the request originates locally or remotely, all php requests still require some form of HTTP server?

Comment: You can run a PHP script in a standalone way using the PHp command line. refer to PHP docs for more information. However, in case you want to render it as a web page, you would require a web server

Answer (score 0):

If you can run PHP on local machine, your machine is probably installed with web server with PHP interpreter (either Apache with PHP, XAMPP, MAMP or similar software installed).